# set onclick event on bootstrap 3.2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, click

I am using Bootstrap 3.2 in my project. I have a dropdown box. I need to fire click event when user select items in it. I tried lots of option but was unsuccessful.

```
<div class="minict_wrapper active">
  <input type="text" value="Default sorting" placeholder="Sort by fee: low to high">

  <ul style="display: block;">
    <li data-value="Default sorting" class="minict_first">Default sorting</li>
    <li data-value="rating" class="">Sort by average rating</li>
    <li data-value="date" class="">Sort by newness</li>
    <li data-value="price" class="selected">Sort by fee: low to high</li>
    <li data-value="price-desc" class="minict_last">Sort by fee: high to low</li>
    <li class="minict_empty" style="display: none;">No results match your keyword.</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Is there any way to to attach jquery click event on this dropdown box?

Answer (score 1):

This code should works.

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $('div.minict_wrapper ul li').on('click', function(){
    //your code...
  });
});
```

Comment: I can not add id to select as this code is generated by Bootstrap plugin.

Comment: ianaya89: Thanks for your answer. The mentioned code worked for me.